# How to add dynamically FormControl to FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sT94PRSy1yXSks6RxPhj?p=preview). I am creating form components dynamically, based on `model` (defined in `app.ts`), and cannot add

`formControlName = "name"`

to the component. In the `control-factory.directive.ts` I add

`this.form.addControl(this.model.name, new FormControl());`,

but how can I bind the value?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/cHis6CGClUvhI7PjDxgO?p=preview

Comment: Thasnks, please add this as answer, so I can accept it

Comment: that could also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55334283/reactive-forms-how-to-add-new-formgroup-or-formarray-into-an-existing-formgroup

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To keep form value in sync with your custom model i would subscribe to `control.valueChanges`

```
let control = new FormControl(this.model.data);
control.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
  this.model.data = x;
});
this.form.addControl(this.model.name, control);
```

to keep in sync form model and view i would bind `FormControl` to reactive directive i.e. `formControl`

**datepicker.component.html**

```
<input [formControl]="form.get(model.name)">
```

**[Modified Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cHis6CGClUvhI7PjDxgO?p=preview)**